# Where's the mistake in my Python program?

Tags: python-3.6

Where are the mistakes in my code? I can't find them. I had to make a multiplication learning program but I am stuck now at something.

```
    import random

n = int(input("How many exercises?"))
wrong = 0
abort = False
for k in range(n):
    a = random.randint(2, 13)
    b = random.randint(2, 13)
    help = str(k+1) + ". " + str(a) + " * " + str(b)
    answer = input(help + "=> ")
    if answer == "":
        abort = True
        break
    if answer !=a * b:
        print("Wrong!")
        wrong += 1
    if abort == True:
        print("Noob")
            return
if wrong == 0:
    print("Good")

else:
    print("Hale" ,wrong)
```

Comment: Asap please? Folk willing to answer questions for free will not share your sense of urgency.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Asking a question properly is **much** more likely to get you an answer quickly than filling in the minimum text requirement with noise about urgency.

Comment: In order for readers to work out the mistakes in your code, they will need to see input data, expected output data, and actual output data. Whilst it looks like people are willing to guess about the problems in your code, would you add these things to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly corrected your code :

1. Indent your code ; it is really important
2. You can't use the statement "return" outside a function
3. Cast "answer" to int if you want to compare it to "a * b" OR cast a * b to string

Here is the correction i've made :

```
import random

n = int(input("How many exercises?"))
wrong = 0
abort = False
for k in range(n):
    a = random.randint(2, 13)
    b = random.randint(2, 13)
    help = str(k+1) + ". " + str(a) + " * " + str(b)
    answer = input(help + "=> ")
    if answer == "":
      abort = True
      break
    if answer != str(a * b):
      print("Wrong!")
      wrong += 1
    if abort == True:
      print("Noob")
if wrong == 0:
    print("Good")

'''Don't know what you wanted to do here
else:
  print("Hale" ,vigu)'''
```

Comment: Whilst this is a nice attempt at an answer, if I were you I would avoid answering such poor questions as they are likely to get closed off and deleted; and your time wasted.

Comment: I'm a bit new to stackoverflow, thank you for telling me. I also improve myself by reading and try to correct this kind of code :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors,  return is not in a function, the vigu variable has no value at that point, and you never get to

if abort == True:
    print("Noob")
        return

because before that you set abort=True and then you do a break,

Comment: Whilst this is a nice attempt at an answer, if I were you I would avoid answering such poor questions as they are likely to get closed off and deleted; and your time wasted.

Comment: Thanks for the comment